# Python automatic bot email sender

Tags: python, email, bots

Im trying to make my email bot send more than 1 email at a time. is there a way to help?

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage
import os

# Define email sender and receiver
email_sender = 'email username'
email_password = 'email password'
email_receiver = 'email whos recieving it'

# Set the subject and body of the email
subject = ''
body = """

"""

em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = email_sender
em['To'] = email_receiver
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)

# Add SSL (layer of security)
context = ssl.create_default_context()

# Log in and send the email
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
    smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
    smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, em.as_string())
```

I tried to make it so that it would do 5 or more at a time and it cant.

Comment: "*it didnt even send 1*" What makes you say that? Did you get an error? If yes, please [edit] to post the error message. You should focus your question first on getting it to send _just_ 1 email correctly and w/o errors, before trying to do multiple at a time.

Comment: sorry i ment it cant do 5 it can do 1.

Comment: Have you looked at Python's [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module?